# Efficiently Filling A Two-Dimensional Space

Tags: geometry, tiling, sorting

I was wondering if there is a formal name for an equation I am dealing with at work. For the problem, I am given five values (for example) that are dimensions in the form of $(x,y)$ (width of a page, height of a page in reality). I have a second value of the same $(x,y)$ form that represents a maximum $(x,y)$ dimension. Is there a formula for filtering through $n$ number of $(x,y)$ pairs and finding how to most efficiently fit as many of these pairs within the maximum dimensions?

Also for clarity the list of five $(x,y)$ pairs is not five repetitions of the same pair but rather different pairs.

Comment: A name  ? "Rectangle packing ?"

Comment: Thank you very much I was having the issue of not being able to properly articulate what I was thinking in my head @JeanMarie

Comment: This is an optimization problem (look up things like rectangular cutting problem). The solution process is not an equation but an algorithm. You may find it difficult to find details on the algorithm as it is a significant practical problem (and hence valuable).